# Way to sort name by ignoring a specific word, for example 'company', whether the word contain or not?

Tags: php, substring, sql-order-by, trim

I want to sort the company name by alphabetically whether the name contain "Company" or not.

```
SELECT *
FROM company_detail
ORDER BY comp_name
```

In db, comp_name was something like

```
Company A
E
B Company
F Company
Company H
D
C Company
Company G
```

Is possible create ORDER BY, when result of ordering will be:

```
Company A
B Company
C Company
D
E
F Company
Company G
Company H
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that maybe ?

```
SELECT comp_name, REPLACE(comp_name, 'Company', '') as c
FROM company_detail
ORDER BY c
```

Comment: You can also just directly `ORDER BY REPLACE(comp_name, 'Company ', '')` if you don't want to add an extra column

Comment: Thanks a lot @apokryfos :):) Both work for me. I've tried substring and trim (didn't work, maybe something need to complete). This is the simplest way that I didn't think of.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kozame :):) too:):)

Comment: @Yadanar Please, valid my answer if that help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this- 
*SELECT * FROM company_detail WHERE comp_name NOT LIKE '%company' ORDER by comp_name asc
SELECT * FROM company_detail WHERE comp_name NOT LIKE 'company%' ORDER by comp_name asc*

Merge the 2 query and set **distinct**. 
Maybe this will help.